# How do I identify if the Perfume is not a replica/counterfeit /fake?

Tags: personal-care

I buy a lot of designer perfumes and shoes, and only recently I have discovered that there are dozens of retailers who are selling fake and lower quality perfumes which looks exactly like the original one.

Here is what happen,
I went to buy **Blue De CHANEL**, and the shopkeeper had asked me if I need the original one or the master copy, I was shocked to hear that there are actually replicas available for these branded perfumes.

I asked him whats the difference between the two, and he says the original one lasts longer then the fake one, other than that, they are the same.

He then showed me both the perfumes and I smelled them, but both were exactly similar to me, in fact, it was almost impossible for me to tell which one is real. He then told me that the original one has a magnet in his cap, and it automatically attached to the bottler when it is close enough.

While this shopkeeper may be honest enough to tell me which one is original, I am worried about other perfumes that I buy every month. I don't think having a magnet in the bottle cap makes it original, because if someone can replicate the scent, bottle and the design, then they can add the magnet in the bottle cap as well, no big deal.

Is there any trick in the book which may help me identifying if the perfume is original or the fake. ?

Here is the photo of the perfume,

[image]

The fake one looked exactly the same.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead with the public service announcement and suggest you not wear any scent.  Some people are allergic to them and many people don't like the smell.  So the hack is don't buy any perfume.

Answer (score 3):

You don't see them, you don't taste them, you *smell* them! If you can't smell a difference, ask yourself what you're actually doing! If you need the prestige, go buy in a top shop where you'll be seen buying the right thing. If the scent is what matters, choose blindfolded and get what smells best to you or to the person you want to impress.

Answer (score 1):

Precise analysis such as careful [gas chromatography](http://www.perkinelmer.com/CMSResources/Images/44-155954APP_011482_01_CharacterizationofPerfumeFragrances.pdf) and [mass spectrometry](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165993602008075) might show a difference, if the counterfeiter is inaccurate. It would need to be carried out over the lifetime of the scent, since it is claimed the the original product has greater [lastingness](http://www.schaefer-marketresearch.com/htdocs_en/infoletter/archiv/SCHAEFER_ResearchReport_02_13_en.pdf), which could be achieved by microencapsulation, chemical synthesis, etc. On the other hand, it would be possible to counterfeit a fragrance perfectly, so that it is indistinguishable from the original -- after all, they are both produced using a formula.